# How to install HPLIP 3.20.3 or above in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, hplip

When trying to install HPLIP 3.20.5 or 3.20.9 it crashes due to dependency problem mainly because of pyqt5 and lot of other dependencies.
If I tried to install those dependencies manually some of them are not listed in Ubuntu repository. From where I will get those dependencies.
Thanks for any help...

Comment: What is your HP device model? What was wrong with simple `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`?

Comment: Unable to communicate with device (code=12): hp:/usb/DeskJet_5820_series?serial=CN7CB5G2DC06BP

Comment: HP Deskjet Gt 5821 - It was working in 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 4535 All-In-One printer and the HPLIP version 3.21.2 works on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. However, I must point out that the first installation of the HPLIP package (downloaded from the HPLIP website because the Ubuntu's package did not work) did not install properly. It failed to install my printer in wireless mode. But second time I went ahead and installed the printer in USB mode. It required a rebooting of the system. And currently it is working fine in USB mode and even the scanning function works smoothly. The GUI tray still poses problem.